# Tailing a file using php and javascript, jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I thought of using javascript and php to tail a file within my browser, by continuously sending request to the server, the server then sends the last line of a log file.

**First.** - I set up the logfile so I can identify it's parts, the time, the message, and the message type.

**e.g.**
    [T]10:31:29[/T] [t]note[/t] [P]Some message in here[/P]

There's no problem in that, I have parsed that correctly. Every line in my log file looks like that.

Now, I used a function that returns the last line of the log file and throw it to the browser.

```
function get_last_line(){
  $line = '';
  $file = "logs/testlog(".date('m-d-Y').").txt";
  $f = fopen($file, 'r');
  $cursor = -1;
  fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
  $char = fgetc($f);
  while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
  }
  while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") { 
    $line = $char . $line;
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
  }

  return $line;
}
```

**usage example**

```
$str = get_last_line();
# returns [T]10:31:29[/T] [t]note[/t] [P]Some message in here[/P]

return json_encode(parse($str));
```

In that case, I received an object out of the last line of the file, but that is not quite right because it only returns the last line of the file, and will not show every log from the file every moment after I have access the "browser tail"

**Now**

What I thought is that I could use the current time from the client to send a request and return all logs that have the same timestamp as the request. Would that be correct? How would I do that?